# How to remove the check mark on another click?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make a table that user can select and deselect with a check mark:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{
    ...;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ...;
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    ...;
}
```

I was trying to remove the check mark when clicking on the check-marked cell again, but it takes 2 clicks to do that instead of one.

If I set selection style to default, when I click on a selected row, it removes the blue highlight; clicking again, it removes the check mark.

I also tried some conditional statements in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but they only respond to second click as well.

What causes the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSUInteger index = [[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] indexOfObject:indexPath];

  if (index != NSNotFound) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex:index];
    if ([cell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
      [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
      [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
  }
}
```

This should toggle the cell's checkmark on every touch.
If you additionally want only one cell to appear selected at a time, also add the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger index = [[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] indexOfObject:indexPath];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex:index];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
}
```

If you don't want the blue hilight background, simply set the cell's selection style to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` once you create the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Starter's link to Apple docs (my code in Swift 3):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

The main point is to keep track of currently selected cell and change cell.accessoryType accordingly. Also don't forget to properly set cell.accessoryType in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) based on selectedIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html) Apple official doc

best solution ever

Comment: Why is this the 'best solution ever'?

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       if (index != NSNotFound) {
              UITableViewCell *cell = [[tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex:index];
              if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
                 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
             else
                 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
             [self.tableName reloadData];
        }
}
```

This helps in toggling the checkmarks (remove the check mark when clicking on the check-marked cell again)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

You can use this:

if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark { tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none } else { tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark } tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

Comment: Please add explanation to answer